# 'On a system' versus 'in a system'

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I was wondering if anyone here could help me with this. I had submitted a written IT proposal to a senior member of the team that I am part of, and she corrected the usage of the word 'on' in the proposal.

I mentioned the following sentence in the proposal:
The 'encoding key' parameter value needs to be set to '62154' on ACUE.

She insisted that this is how it should be worded:
The 'encoding key' parameter value needs to be set to '62154' in ACUE.

*** ACUE is a software

Can anyone here advise on which of the 2 sentences above is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your team member is correct.  When using a particular system you are said to be "in" that system.

Comment: Thanks Williams, that was quick! Just curious, is it wrong though to use 'on' instead of 'in' in the above context? 'encoding key' is a configuration within the software, and the proposal is intended to describe the expected setting of a configuration to the client..

Comment: Expanded my comment into an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a particular system you are said to be "in" that system.

However, when using a particular **version** of some software, you might say that you are "on version 12".

In this case, i think the "system" rule applies (especially since you use the word "system" in your question title), so it's "in" - your team member is correct.